# Search farm and Kerberos

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search

We are currently planning a SharePoint Server 2013 search farm that will index SharePoint sites, Documentum and DFS enabled file shares.

Is it recommended to configure Kerberos for this scenario or will it add an extra complexity level without any real added value ?

As far as I know, Kerberos is heavily used when dealing with BI in SharePoint, but in this case, I'm not sure if it's really interesting to configure it or not.

Thanks.